# Dovecot Failed to initialize SSL server context

Tags: ssl, dovecot

I'm trying to configure TLS for Dovecot 2.3 but after setting all things up I'm not able to start  Dovecot:

```
Apr 16 20:56:02 master: Info: Dovecot v2.3.9.3 (9f41b88fa) starting up for imap, pop3, lmtp (core dumps disabled)
Apr 16 20:56:25 auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/auth
Apr 16 20:56:25 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/auth/lib20_auth_var_expand_crypt.so
Apr 16 20:56:25 auth: Debug: Read auth token secret from /usr/var/run/dovecot/auth-token-secret.dat
Apr 16 20:56:25 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=30750)
Apr 16 20:56:25 imap-login: Error: Failed to initialize SSL server context: Can't load SSL private key: Key is for a different cert than ssl_cert: user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<JKh/qm6j/rMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Apr 16 20:56:25 imap-login: Info: Disconnected: TLS initialization failed. (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<JKh/qm6j/rMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Apr 16 20:57:47 master: Fatal: Dovecot is already running with PID 30727 (read from /usr/var/run/dovecot/master.pid)
Apr 16 20:57:47 master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=30823 uid=0 code=kill)
```

I have created a brand new key pair, csr and the cert but still it complains to start.

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is that your dh.pem file does not have enough bits.
generate your own dh.pem file with the following command:

```
openssl dhparam -out /etc/dovecot/dh.pem 4096
```

Then add / uncomment the line:

```
ssl_dh=</usr/share/dovecot/dh.pem
```

to/in => /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf

Comment: It didn't solve. Are we talking about the same ? I see this error: `lmtp(350682): Error: SSL context initialization failed, disabling SSL: Can't load SSL private key (ssl_key setting): Key is for a different cert than ssl_cert`

Answer (score 1):

"Can't load SSL private key: Key is for a different cert than ssl_cert:"

Use `doveconf -n -P` to output the actual dovecot configuration you're running.

Look for something like :

ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/ssl.pem
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/ssl.pem

You may need to do something like :

`openssl x509 -in /path/to/ssl.pem -noout -text`

on both of your certificate files to confirm that the ssl_key file doesn't match the ssl_cert file.

Comment: Yeah. This comment was useful to me. It is not the solution but it points to the fact that `.crt` file and `.key` file must be different. Which consequently means that something is wrong with the keypair. I got rid off the error message finally. How ? There should be a `dovecot.pem` file in `/etc/pki/dovecot/certs/` and another `dovecot.pem` in `/etc/pki/dovecot/private/` . Obvious which is which. I changed the `dovecot.conf` accordingly. Service started w/o any error.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment because I'm new, but at least part of your problem is the key pair even though you have created new ones.  Where did you get your keys & certificates. Consider using letsencrypt & certbot. Certbot will put certificates Private Key & Certificate files into (/etc/letsencrypt/live on linux). Then in your dovecot.conf set ssl_cert, ssl_key & ssl_ca to the correct location and restart doveot. Don't reload, there are known issues with pid errors. Stop dovecot and restart.